# Plot time-series: Get date on x-axis

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following data:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Date_Quandl = c("31.12.2000", "31.03.2001", "30.06.2001", 
"30.09.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.03.2002", "30.06.2002", "30.09.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.03.2003", "30.06.2003", "30.09.2003", "31.12.2003", 
"31.03.2004", "30.06.2004", "30.09.2004", "31.12.2004", "31.03.2005", 
"30.06.2005", "30.09.2005", "31.12.2005", "31.03.2006", "30.06.2006", 
"30.09.2006", "31.12.2006", "31.03.2007", "30.06.2007", "30.09.2007", 
"31.12.2007", "31.03.2008", "30.06.2008", "30.09.2008", "31.12.2008", 
"31.03.2009", "30.06.2009", "30.09.2009", "31.12.2009", "31.03.2010", 
"30.06.2010", "30.09.2010", "31.12.2010", "31.03.2011", "30.06.2011", 
"30.09.2011", "31.12.2011", "31.03.2012", "30.06.2012", "30.09.2012", 
"31.12.2012", "31.03.2013", "30.06.2013", "30.09.2013", "31.12.2013", 
"31.03.2014", "30.06.2014", "30.09.2014", "31.12.2014"), Date_Quartal = c("Q4-2000", 
"Q1-2001", "Q2-2001", "Q3-2001", "Q4-2001", "Q1-2002", "Q2-2002", 
"Q3-2002", "Q4-2002", "Q1-2003", "Q2-2003", "Q3-2003", "Q4-2003", 
"Q1-2004", "Q2-2004", "Q3-2004", "Q4-2004", "Q1-2005", "Q2-2005", 
"Q3-2005", "Q4-2005", "Q1-2006", "Q2-2006", "Q3-2006", "Q4-2006", 
"Q1-2007", "Q2-2007", "Q3-2007", "Q4-2007", "Q1-2008", "Q2-2008", 
"Q3-2008", "Q4-2008", "Q1-2009", "Q2-2009", "Q3-2009", "Q4-2009", 
"Q1-2010", "Q2-2010", "Q3-2010", "Q4-2010", "Q1-2011", "Q2-2011", 
"Q3-2011", "Q4-2011", "Q1-2012", "Q2-2012", "Q3-2012", "Q4-2012", 
"Q1-2013", "Q2-2013", "Q3-2013", "Q4-2013", "Q1-2014", "Q2-2014", 
"Q3-2014", "Q4-2014"), oenb_dependent = c(1.0227039, -5.0683144, 
0.6657713, 3.3161374, -2.1586704, -0.7833623, -0.2203209, 2.416144, 
-1.7625406, -0.1565037, -7.9803936, 9.4594715, -4.8104584, 8.4827107, 
-6.1895262, 1.4288595, 1.4896459, -0.4198522, -5.1583964, 5.2502294, 
1.0567102, -1.0923342, -1.5852298, 0.6061936, -0.3752335, 2.5008664, 
-1.3999729, 2.2802166, -2.1468756, -1.4890328, -0.79254376, 3.21804705, 
-0.94407886, -0.27802316, -0.20753079, -1.12610048, 2.0883735, 
-0.7424854, 0.44203729, -1.48905938, 1.39644424, -3.8917377, 
11.25665848, -9.22884035, 3.26856762, -0.00179541, -2.39664325, 
4.00455574, -5.60891295, 4.6556348, -4.40536951, 6.64234497, 
-7.34787319, 7.56303006, -8.23083674, 4.43247855, 1.31090412), 
    carReg = c(0.73435946, 0.24001161, 16.90532537, -14.60281976, 
    6.47603166, -8.35815849, 3.55576685, 7.10705794, -4.6955223, 
    10.9623709, 5.5801857, -6.4499936, -9.46196502, 9.36289122, 
    -8.52630424, 5.45070994, -4.5346405, -2.26716538, 2.56870398, 
    0.013737, 5.7750101, -27.1060826, 1.08977179, 4.94934712, 
    17.55391859, -13.91160577, 10.38981128, -11.81349246, -0.0831467, 
    2.79748237, 1.84865463, -1.98736934, -6.24191695, 13.33602659, 
    -3.86527871, 0.78720993, 4.73360651, -4.1674034, 9.37426802, 
    -5.90660464, -0.4915792, -5.84811629, 9.67648643, -6.96872719, 
    -7.6535767, 0.24847595, 0.18685263, -2.28766949, 1.1544631, 
    -3.87636933, -2.4731545, 4.33876671, 1.08836339, 5.64525271, 
    1.90743854, -3.94709355, -0.84611324), cpi = c(1.16, -3.26, 
    0.22, -3.51, 0.84, -2.81, -0.34, -4.57, -0.12, -3.95, -1.37, 
    -2.73, 0.35, -5.38, -4.43, -3.08, 0.74, -3.03, -1.09, -2, 
    0.35, -1.52, 1.28, 0.2, -0.25, -4.55, -2.49, -4.24, -0.31, 
    -2.96, -2.24, -0.46, -0.06, -2.67, -1.27, -1.4, -0.7, -0.96, 
    -2.18, -2.53, -0.52, -1.74, -2.18, -1.4, -0.34, -0.09, -1.65, 
    -1.15, -0.17, -2.01, -1.38, -1.24, 0.09, -2.44, -1.92, -2.61, 
    -0.34), primConstTot = c(-0.33334, -0.93333, -0.16667, -0.33333, 
    -0.16667, -0.86666, -0.3, -0.4, -0.26667, -1.56667, -0.73333, 
    0.1, -0.23333, -0.26667, -1.5774, -0.19284, 0.38568, -2.42423, 
    -0.93663, 0.08265, -0.63361, 0.0551, -0.49587, 2.39668, -1.70798, 
    -3.36085, -2.56196, 0.16529, 0, -1.84572, -1.3774, -0.49586, 
    -1.70798, -1.90081, -0.55096, -0.77134, -0.16529, -0.30303, 
    -0.17066, -0.23853, -0.64401, -1.52657, -1.57426, -0.28623, 
    -0.54861, -1.07336, -0.71558, 0.02385, -0.38164, -1.09721, 
    0, 0.14311, -0.38164, -1.02566, -0.42934, -0.35779, -0.4532
    ), resProp.Dwell = c(0.8, -4, -3.2, 2.7, -1.6, -1, -2.4, 
    -0.4, -0.8, 1, -12.1, 0.2, -5.2, 3.7, -2.7, -1.7, 1.5, 0.7, 
    -7.9, 0.3, 0.3, 1.4, -3.3, -1, -1.6, 1.5, 0.5, 1.5, -1, -2.2, 
    -3.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.9, -0.4, -3.4, 0.9, 0.1, -0.2, -2.8, -0.8, 
    -6.2, 11.3, -4.6, 1, 1.1, -1.7, 4.1, -5, 2.3, -2.3, 4.6, 
    -6.3, 6.3, -6.9, 0, 2.4), cbre.office.primeYield = c(0, 0, 
    0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 
    0.1, 0.05, 0.15, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0, -0.15, -0.85, 
    -1, -0.85, -0.75, -0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
    0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cbre.retail.capitalValue = c(-1882.35294, 
    230.76923, -230.76923, -226.41509, -670.78117, -436.13707, 
    -222.22223, 0, -205.91233, -202.16847, 0, -393.5065, -403.91909, 
    -186.30647, -539.81107, -748.11463, -764.70588, -311.47541, 
    -301.42782, -627.09677, -480, 720, 782.6087, 645.96273, 251.42857, 
    1386.66667, -533.33334, -533.33333, -533.33333, 0, 0, -1024.56141, 
    -192.10526, 0, -730, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -834.28571, 0, -1450.93168, 
    0, 0, 0, -700.78261, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1452, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Date_Quandl", 
"Date_Quartal", "oenb_dependent", "carReg", "cpi", "primConstTot", 
"resProp.Dwell", "cbre.office.primeYield", "cbre.retail.capitalValue"
), row.names = c(NA, -57L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000200788>)
> plot(data$oenb_dependent, type="l" )
```

[image]

I want to plot my time so that I also get on the `x-axis` the responsible date of the data point from column `data$Date_Quandl`.

Any suggestions how to get this?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to convert to an `xts` object and then `plot`

```
library(xts)
xt1 <- xts(data$oenb_dependent, order.by= as.Date(data$Date_Quandl, '%d.%m.%Y'))
plot(xt1, main='Plot of oenb_dependent')
```

[image]

We could also change the 'Date' format in the x-axis using `major.format`

```
plot(xt1, main='Plot of oenb_dependent', major.format='%b-%d-%Y')
```